# vb.net How to declare thread and call functions with it

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I'm trying to use a thread to translate every text found in the Windows Forms to make my system multi-language.

I have a separate class named 'Language' with a sub and a function, sub reads a language source file, and function translates by receiving and returning a string.

Then I have my first Windows Form where I declare my thread:

---

```
    Dim ThreadTraductor As New Thread(AddressOf ...) 'don't know how to do it

    Dim cultureInfo As New System.Globalization.CultureInfo(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings('en').ToString)

    ThreadTraductor.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo
    ThreadTraductor.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo
```

---

Basically I'm creating this thread to have a background process translating every Windows Form that's opened during execution, problem is I don't know how to declare it properly since I don't want to include any parameter when declaring, but I want the thread to be called from different Forms with parameters to translate, and also I want the thread to use my translate method inside Language class, is that possible? How? 
Please assist, I haven't use threads before.

Comment: You're not going to have any joy if you want the new thread to access any of the data on your Windows Forms and to update them. You can only access and update the UI from the UI thread. Why do you think threading is useful here? There are other was to do translations.

Comment: What you should do is show how this would work **without** threads and then ask us for advice on using threads then. This is just too hard to answer with all this vagueness.

Answer (score 0):

Public Class Lenguaje 'Class used to read language source file and translate strings

```
Public dicIdioma As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

Public Sub LeerArchivo(ByVal Culture As String)

    Dim vectorAux() As String
    dicIdioma.Clear()

    Try
        Dim LectorArchivo As New StreamReader("C:\Users\Joaqo\Desktop\Dorian VB\DorianBdBv1.0\UI\bin\Debug\" + Culture + ".txt")

        Dim line As String

        While Not LectorArchivo.Peek = -1
            line = LectorArchivo.ReadLine()
            vectorAux = line.Split(":")
            dicIdioma.Add(vectorAux(0), vectorAux(1))
        End While

    Catch ex As System.IO.FileNotFoundException
        MessageBox.Show("No se encuentra el archivo de idioma.")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub

Public Function Traducir(ByRef frase As String) As String

    Dim StringAux As String

    For Each Item As String In dicIdioma.Keys

        If Item = Char.ToLower(frase(0)) & frase.Substring(1) Then
            StringAux = Char.ToUpper(dicIdioma.Item(Item)(0)) & dicIdioma.Item(Item).Substring(1)
            frase = StringAux.Replace("_", " ")

        ElseIf Item.Replace("_", " ") = Char.ToLower(frase(0)) & frase.Substring(1) Then
            StringAux = Char.ToUpper(dicIdioma.Item(Item)(0)) & dicIdioma.Item(Item).Substring(1)
            frase = StringAux.Replace("_", " ")

        End If
    Next

    Return frase

End Function
```

End Class

---

Then I iterate every text object in my Windows Forms to translate them:

```
    For Each Item As Label In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Label)()
        Item.Text = Traductor.Traducir(Item.Text)
    Next

    For Each Item As Button In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)()
        Item.Text = Traductor.Traducir(Item.Text)
    Next
```

And it works just fine, but I'd be calling Traductor, Lenguaje's instance declared on my first interface, from the whole app, isn't that wrong somehow?

I was told that I should use Culture and CultureUI for this, but I'm not familiarized with that. What do you think? Sorry if I'm missing something, it's my first question here.